# Mercurial clone russian symbols like '?'

Tags: linux, encoding, mercurial, cyrillic

I work in Linux Red Hat 4.1.2-48 from PuTTy where set encoding UTF-8(PuTTy).I installed mercurial 2.2.1 and his repository. In 'hgrc' file of repository encoding set UTF-8 like :

```
[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
encoding = UTF-8

[diff]
git = True
ignorews = True
ignorewsamount = True
ignoreblanklines = True
```

In repository i have files, which names are in utf-8 encoding, and have russian symbols. When i go to repositories directory i see right russian symbols. In Linux enviroment variable `LANG=en_US.UTF-8.`.

If i clone this repositoru on windows 7, i have right russian symbols and everything is fine. But if i clone on that Linux all russian symbols become '?' character. When i execute command `file -bi`  it's say that it's utf8.

Can anybody help solve this problem to Russian characters were Russian or say direction of problem?

Comment: if it works on Windows 7 and doesn't work on Linux, then it sounds like a filename encoding issue - different platforms use different encoding for file names. there is an extension - http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixUtf8Extension which should help in this situation

Comment: Thanks, but i don't understand. "This extension corrects filename encoding problems on Windows.", but everything is fine on windows. Problem in Linux and more specifically in mercurial clone operation or mercurail config. I think so becouse in windows all is fine and in Linux is problem.

Comment: Check you terminal can actually display non roman chars: echo -e "\xE2\x98\xA0" - if it displays ??? then its just a problem with you terminal .

Comment: i solved it. By testing i discover, that if i set LANG enviroment variable by en_US.cp1251, clone operation give files with right russian symbols. I need it because team city can't copy files with names like '??..'. So i set build parameter to LANG=en_US.cp1251 and it earned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with character set issue between windows and Linux, I ran into similar problem. for me everything is ok on Linux and not OK on windows. [CharacterEncodingOnWindows](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CharacterEncodingOnWindows) has the insight into this issue.

Comment: You need to paste the relevant content of the article you are referring to here on stackoverflow.